# Canvas HTML | Track a line perpendicular to two point and passing through a point

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, html5-canvas, geometry-surface

In a html canvas I draw a line starting from point A and ending at point B.
I should, given a point C, draw a line perpendicular to the line from A and B and that passes from C.

Below is how I create the line that passes from A and B (the points are taken as input, for convenience in this example they are supplied by variable.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 100);
ctx.lineTo(150, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Now given C (for example C = 80, 130) I would like to draw a line that is perpendicular to the line between A and B and that passes from C
How can I calculate points that allow me to create this line?

For example this:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 100);
ctx.lineTo(150, 100);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(80, 10);
ctx.lineTo(80, 130);
 ctx.arc(80, 130, 2, 0, 360, false); // C
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Thanks so much for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the not trivial (line isn't vertical or horizontal) case, you just need to know that the gradient of the perpendicular line is minus one over the gradient of the line. I hope the below code snippet helps.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var pointA = {
  x: 0.0,
  y: 0.0
};
var pointB = {
  x: 200.0,
  y: 150.0
};
var pointC = {
  x: 80.0,
  y: 130.0
};
var pointD = {
  x: 0.0,
  y: 0.0
};

if (pointA.y == pointB.y) { // AB is horizontal
  pointD.x = pointC.x
  pointD.y = pointA.y
} else if (pointA.x == pointB.x) { // AB is vertical
  pointD.x = pointA.x
  pointD.y = pointC.y
} else { // need some geometry
  var gradientOfAB = (pointA.y - pointB.y) / (pointA.x - pointB.x);
  var interceptOfAB = pointA.y - gradientOfAB * pointA.x;

  var gradientOfCD = -1 / gradientOfAB;
  var interceptOfCD = pointC.y - gradientOfCD * pointC.x;

  pointD.x = (interceptOfAB - interceptOfCD) / (gradientOfCD - gradientOfAB);
  pointD.y = gradientOfCD * pointD.x + interceptOfCD;
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);
ctx.lineTo(pointB.x, pointB.y);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(pointD.x, pointD.y);
ctx.lineTo(pointC.x, pointC.y);
ctx.arc(pointC.x, pointC.y, 2, 0, 360, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks so much!
How could I get the second line to continue until y = 0?

var pointA = {x: 40, y: 100}
var pointB = {x: 250.0,y: 150.0}
var pointC = {x: 150.0,y: 140.0}
var pointD = {x: 180.0,y: 0.0}

Comment: provided line AB isn't horizontal or vertical you just need to change `pointD.x = (interceptOfAB - interceptOfCD) / (gradientOfCD - gradientOfAB);
  pointD.y = gradientOfCD * pointD.x + interceptOfCD;` to `pointD.y = 0; 
  pointD.x = -interceptOfCD / gradientOfCD;`